# accordion | Click of input box accordion is expanding

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, accordion

i am using a javascript function to eexpand and collapse of accordion. i want to expand one item at a time and alos when i try to add some text into input box then also accordion is expanding.
    pls refer ''''https://jsfiddle.net/nehajain/d8ozr9m4/

```
i want except from the input box, wherever i clicked on the heading button, accordion will expand
```

Comment: ```<input type="text" value="abc" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true">``` this should do the stuff, but maybe there are better solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code snippet, you're changing styles for clicked panel and not doing anything to already open accordion. You need to update styles for other open accordion and make them hidden.

So I've updated that code to use classes and on click removing classes from all panels and toggling for a clicked panel.

Following code will make sure that at a time only one accordion is open

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get list of panels
    const panels = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
    // get panel for clicked button
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    for(let i = 0; i < panels.length; i++){
      // if panel is not equal to clicked panel then remove class
      if(panel != panels[i]){
        panels[i].classList.remove('active-panel');
      }     
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");    
    panel.classList.toggle('active-panel');
  });
}
```

working jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/2f9ndcer/